# How to pass form text value as a c# parameter on Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a function that fetch the data based on the user's registration number on the active directory and print it to the textbox fields on the modal. In that case I need to send as a parameter whatever is written in the textbox instead of the field numbered 31919 in the code below.

```
<center>
    <image style="margin-top: 20px; width: 25%;" src="/images/adduser.png"></image>
    <div style="margin-top: 25px;">
          <form method="post">
                <label class="control-label"><b>Reg. No</b></label> 
                <input type="text" name="RegNo" id="RegNo" value="">
                <button onclick="created(1)" style="margin-left: 15px; height: 60%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddUser1" type="button" class="btn btn-light-primary px-6 font-weight-bold">Fetch</button>
                <span id="spin"><i style="position: relative; display: inline-block;" class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i></span>
          </form>
      @{
            FetchDataFromAD("31919");
      }
        <hr />
    </div>
</center>
```

So, basically I'm trying to do something like this:

```
 @{
     FetchDataFromAD(RegNo.Text);
 }
```

P.S.: `FetchDataFromAD` just a function that modifying string expressions like that:

```
public void FetchDataFromAD(string RegNo)
{    
    System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher search = new System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher(directoryEntry);
    search.Filter = "(postalCode=" + RegNo + ")";
    foreach (System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult sResultSet in search.FindAll())
    {
        // Ad
        FetchADPersonelName = GetProperty(sResultSet, "cn");
        FetchADTitle = GetProperty(sResultSet, "title");
        FetchADNetworkN = GetProperty(sResultSet, "samaccountname");
        FetchADEmail = GetProperty(sResultSet, "mail");
        FetchADAdress = "2";
        // FetchADDepartman = GetProperty(sResultSet, "department");

    }
}
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: that `FetchDataFromAD("31919");` is happening at the time the page is rendered on the server, before it is sent to the user. In other words, the user has not yet had an opportunity to enter any values into the text box. To do what you're talking about, you will have to use some javascript to query a method (web service), return the value you are expecting, and write that onto the page

Comment: @Jonathan I can get the function to be called when the button is clicked with javascript, and can get the value in the textbox as a javascript variable but I couldn't send the javascript variable value as a parameter to the c# function. Are there any documents on the subject you're talking about that I can review?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider to use the following:

```
<script>
    function ApplyFilter() {
        var regno = document.getElementById("RegNo").value;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("FetchDataFromAD", "Home")',
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            data: { regno },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            }
        }); 
    };  
</script>

<div style="margin-top: 25px;">       
    <form method="post">
        <label class="control-label"><b>Reg. No</b></label>
        <input type="text" name="RegNo" id="RegNo" value="">
        <button onclick="ApplyFilter()" style="margin-left: 15px; height: 60%;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#AddUser1" type="button" class="btn btn-light-primary px-6 font-weight-bold">Fetch</button>
        <span id="spin"><i style="position: relative; display: inline-block;" class="fas fa-sync fa-spin"></i></span>
    </form>       
    <hr />
</div>
```

And the `FetchDataFromAD()` method signature update to be called from JavaScript:

```cs
public JsonResult FetchDataFromAD(string RegNo)
{
    ... your code here   

    return Json("Filter is applied", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```